# Javascript .length and has class difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle

I'm trying to test the difference between both by applying in the toggle button(change text color and first click and reverse on second click)

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/qhyBL

this works:

```
if($('.changeC').length)
{
    $("div").removeClass("changeC");//reset
}else{
        $("div").addClass("changeC");
    }
```

but not this:

```
if($('div').hasClass(".changeC"))
{
    $("div").removeClass("changeC");//reset
}else{
        $("div").addClass("changeC");
    }
```

why is that so?

Comment: You should have a look at `toggleClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to remove `.` from the argument to [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/#hasClass-className) as it takes the className not the selector.

Use

```
$('div').hasClass("changeC");
```

or alternative way to use the selector is using `.is`

```
$('div').is(".changeC");
```

And to add on, what you trying to do you can achieve that by:

```
$("div").toggleClass("changeC");
```

And of course in your real-time scenario you might want to be more specific on which div to target this operation to since `div` is a too generic a selector, and in such case where you have multiple divs with class changeC  (In your first snippet) wouldn't serve much and may add the class to un-intented divs as well if the length returns 0.